# fread not reading the whole file as expected

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

I'm trying to read a large binary file in C.
I wrote the following code:

```
FILE* f1 =  fopen("filename.exe", "rb");
    if(f1 != NULL)
    {
        fseek(f1,0,SEEK_END);
        long l = ftell(f1);
        fseek(f1,0,SEEK_SET);
        char * buf = (char *)malloc(l* sizeof(char));
        int k = fread(buf,sizeof(buf),1,f1);
        if(k != l)
            printf("the file was not read properly");
    }
```

Now, not only is `k` not equal to `l`, it is much smaller (`l` is ~99,000,000 while `k` is only 13).

Is it possible that `fread` is stopping because it reaches a NULL in the file? What can I do to avoid it?

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` will equal either 4 or 8 depending upon whether you have a 32-bit of 64-bit system. Use `l` instead in `fread`.

Comment: that did not help. still the same result

Comment: fread returns the number of items read. In your case size is l, and the number is 1. fread will return 1. Swap the arguments l and 1.

Comment: great! that worked! thanks! k now equals l. just another problem now, the buf seems to have only the beginning of the file. how can i get the whole file and search for a string in it?

Comment: It's a binary file, so the usual C string routines won't work on it because they will find a 0 before the end of the file.

Comment: so what can i do? i need to read the file, delete a part of it, and write a new file with the edited bytes. how will that be possible?

Comment: Open an output file for write, copy the original file to the output file byte by byte except when you come across the sections you don't want to copy.

Comment: @one: "... delete a part of it"... Is the '.exe' part of your example filename a random sequence of characters, or are you attempting to modify an executable program this way? If the latter, "Good night and Good luck". Read up on the EXE file format (for an exe younger than about 20, skim it then read up on the PE file format instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fread` returns the number of items read. In your case size is `l`, and the number is `1`. fread will return 1. Swap the arguments l and 1.

If you really want to look for an ascii string inside a binary file you can do something like:

```
char *find = ....
int len = strlen(find);
char *end = (buf + l) - len;
for(char *p = buf; p < end; p++) {
    if(strncmp(p, find, len) == 0) {
        // you have found ascii string in buf
    }
}
```

If it's not an ascii string you are looking for use `memcmp`() instead of `strncmp`.